Maintain document state in Preview not working when PDF changed
I am using Emacs and AUCTeX on macOS Sonoma to modify PDFs that are open in Preview 11.0 when they are recompiled.  However, I need to view parameters (page and view height/width) to remain the same when the PDF is recompiled.
I have "Start on the last viewed page" enabled but it doesn't work: when the PDF document is recompiled it shows "Page 8 of 44" as if the page I was on should have been remembered, but it still resets to the first page (and changes to the default view width/height).  I don't think the solution is an Emacs one because the PDF is viewed in Preview.
How I can ensure Preview maintains the state of the PDF when it is recompiled (as it does in TeXShop)?

I think it is not intended for live preview, and the view is refreshed and lost the position when file on disk is changed. You may want to write an applescript to scroll there manually after each refresh
